# Why is my recursive function printing just once in my template?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I want to dynamically build similar components in my templates, so I created this recursive function in my `page_view.ex`:

```
defmodule MyProject.PageView do
  use FabricaASA.Web, :view

defmodule Recursion do
  def buildElements(element,n) when n <= 1 do
    element
  end

  def buildElements(element, n) do
    element
    buildElements(element, n - 1)
  end
end

end
```

Then, in my template I call it using:

```
<%= MyProject.PageView.Recursion.buildElements("LOL", 4) %>
```

The problem is that I'm getting just one LOL instead of 4 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursive version of buildElement has a "no operation" on the first line when you put `element` alone, resulting in just one item returned and the others lost. They should be collected together in an accumulator, e.g a list. Something like:

```
def buildElements(element,n) when n <= 1 do
  [element] # EDIT: Must be a list too
end
def buildElements(element, n) do
  [element | buildElements(element, n - 1)]
end
```

And even better (IMHO) than doing the formatting/concatenation of the list in the computation, you can iterate over it in the template.

```
<%= for element <- MyProject.PageView.Recursion.buildElements("LOL", 4) do %>
  <%= element %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you Lauro. Your first half is OK and works, but when I replace my template call by yours (second half of your response - "And even better...") I get an error (unexpected token ' end ') that I can't understand why...

Comment: Ouch, I missed the `do` a the end of the for call. I updated the answer.

Comment: When trying the second alternative I get an error: `no function clause matching in Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3`. Do I need to change the function in the view?

Comment: What do you mean by the second alternative? The for loop in the template? It should work if you return a list/enum from buildElements. I just used the same structure of the Phoenix guide in http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/templates#section-displaying-lists

Comment: Yes, but I'm getting that error. Never mind, your function works great! Now I tried to extract a dynamic ID from that function and I'm also getting into troubles (see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316858/how-to-add-a-dynamic-id-to-my-recursive-function-in-the-view-that-builds-html-el)