# Error when iterating over a function with two arguments in my template

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have a function in my view that I use to dynamically build HTML elements in my templates:

```
defmodule Recursion do
        def buildElements(element,n) when n <= 1 do
            element
        end
        def buildElements(element, n) do
          [element | buildElements(element, n - 1)]
        end
    end
```

It is working great unless I try to iterate it in my template:

```
<%= for element <- MyProject.PageView.Recursion.buildElements("LOL", 2) do %>
            <%= element %>
   <% end %>
```

I get this error:

```
no function clause matching in Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a small change to solve your problem.

You try to add a element to a list with the `[foo | bar]` notation. `bar` must be a list while `foo` is a single item.

Change your `element` to `[element]` and it's done.

```
def buildElements(element,n) when n <= 1 do
  [element]
end

def buildElements(element, n) do
  [element | buildElements(element, n - 1)]
end
```